# How to Join a list of Dates with another Sub Query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I need to Join a List of Dates with a Subquery.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (WITH daterange(level, dt) 
             AS (SELECT 1, 
                        CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS 
                 FROM   SYSIBM.sysdummy1 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT level + 1, 
                        dt + 1 DAY 
                 FROM   daterange 
                 WHERE  level < 1000 
                        AND dt < CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY) 
        SELECT dt 
         FROM   daterange)a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT WT.task_type_code, 
                                DATE(WT.created_ts) AS d, 
                                COUNT(WT.task_id)   AS COUNTER 
                         FROM   workflow_task WT, 
                                stage_item SI 
                         WHERE  WT.task_type_code IN( 2 ) 
                                AND DATE(WT.created_ts) >= '2016-03-18' 
                                AND DATE(WT.created_ts) <= '2016-03-26' 
                                AND SI.task_id = WT.task_id 
                         GROUP  BY WT.task_type_code, 
                                   DATE(WT.created_ts) 
                         ORDER  BY 2)b 
                     ON( A.dt = b.d ) 
WITH UR;
```

But it throws an error message as

> An error occurred while accessing the database. ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD
>   AS.  TOKEN INNER LEFT RIGHT FULL CROSS JOIN WAS EXPECTED; THE CURSOR
>   SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE

please help me and suggest me how to join !!

Comment: Your query need to execute on sql server, oracle & db2 ?

Comment: Query needs to execute in DB2

Comment: DB2 is not oracle nor is it Sql server. please tag only relevant information in future questions

Comment: a) You don't need `level`, you can just use the date range for your termination condition (it may help the optimizer, too).  b) If you don't have one, look into creating a `Calendar` table.  c) instead of `DATE(TW.created_ts) <= '2016-03-26'` you should be using `TW.created_ts < DATE('2016-03-27')`, which helps the optimizer make better plans (and similar on the other condition).  Also, you should always query date ranges with an exclusive upper-bound like this.  d) Don't use the comma-separated `FROM` syntax, always explicitly list out your joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your query with the `WITH` keyword and remove the outer most SELECT which is not needed anyway.

Comment: Thank You Michael !! Its Executing!!